# Traveling to Seoul, phone questions

Tags: cellphones, south-korea, power

I have an ASUS zenphone 2 (yay for dual sim slots!) and I'm traveling to Seoul next week for a two week business trip.

1) do I need to worry about a power converter for the phone charger, or will the charger itself take care of that?

2) any suggestions on renting a microSIM card for my trip (or whether wifi data calling would be more sensible)? I've got a friend over there now (military) who will be picking me up from the airport, so he can bring something for me if I know what I need...

Comment: What does your phone charger say on it with regards to input voltage (v) and cycles (hz)? Also, you'd buy a SIM, not rent it. Whether it's worth it for 2 weeks or just put up with wifi is your decision (but maybe some answers will help you understand the costs/effort involved)

Comment: @CMaster The charger says 100V-240V 50/60Hz. so it looks like it's good for international travel?

Comment: That cover's pretty much all mains power I've heard of, yes. You may need a plug adapter of course http://www.worldstandards.eu/electricity/plugs-and-sockets/

Answer (score 3):

The standard in South Korea is 220V at 60 Hz. So you don't have to worry about a converter. Depending on where you are from you need an adapter.

The answer to your second question depends on your needs and on the places you are going to.

- If you plan to stay in Seoul or in other metropolitan areas and you want to use internet based phone and message services, you can think about renting a so-called [WiBro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiBro) Egg.
- As an alternative you can rent a smartphone for the length of your stay. That's also a common choice among foreigners. When renting a SIM Card alone, you will have to be sure that it works for your phone. They will check that on-site.

Have a look at what [KT](http://roaming.kt.com/renewal/eng/main.asp) and [SK](https://www.skroaming.com/main.asp) offer, compare and make a choice.

On the other hand, it is not too hard to find public wireless networks in Seoul and in other cities. Some of them are free, and other ones can be used with [prepaid cards](http://first.wifi.olleh.com/en/index_new.html) or with Skype WiFi.

Comment: P.S. In the past I have used the KT OLLEH WiBro Egg to my complete satisfaction ... ;-)